# Memory leak when loading a 2D texture with DX11

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, textures, loading, directx-11

Loading in a texture with no real issues, the ID3D11Texture2D that I'm using to temporarily grab the D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC info seems to not delete properly.

If I don't bother using the ID3D11Texture2D item I don't have memory leaks. When I do use it, despite deleting it after getting what I need, it is left over on shutdown when using the ReportLiveObjects function.

I've tried using my own * and manually deleting it, I've tried using a ComPtr and trying the various ways to free one of those up.

```
Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<ID3D11Texture2D> pTextureInterface = nullptr;
ID3D11Resource *res = nullptr;

HRESULT hres = DirectX::CreateWICTextureFromFileEx(m_pDev, const_cast<wchar_t*>(wStrAddress.c_str()), 0, D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT, D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE, 0, 0, DirectX::WIC_LOADER_IGNORE_SRGB, &res, tempTex.ReleaseAndGetAddressOf());

tempTex->GetResource(&res);
res->QueryInterface<ID3D11Texture2D>(&pTextureInterface);
D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC desc;
pTextureInterface->GetDesc(&desc);

RECT r;
r.left = 0;
r.top = 0;
r.right = desc.Width;
r.bottom = desc.Height;

if (pTextureInterface != nullptr)
{
    pTextureInterface.ReleaseAndGetAddressOf();
    pTextureInterface = nullptr;
}
if (res != nullptr)
{
    res->Release();
    res = nullptr;
}
```

When I create and use the pTextureInterface I get a DirectX memory leak warning for every texture I load with a Refcount of 1.
If I don't bother to use pTextureInterface at all I have no leaks and everything loads and displays properly (except their dimensions as I then am manually setting the rectangle bounds of the source image)

I realize this is probably some tiny little oversight but I have been unable to find a working solution all day, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At invocation `tempTex->GetResource(&res);` naked pointer acquired during the call to `CreateWICTextureFromFileEx` is overwritten without releasing it. So the reference counter for that object is not decremented and object leaks. It looks like `tempTex->GetResource(&res);` is not needed at all.

Comment: That was it. Thanks for the quick answer, it always seems to be the simplest thing. I admittedly don't fully understand how half of the DX stuff works.

Comment: Simplest solution is to use: ``ComPtr<ID3D11Resource> res;`` and get rid of all the explicit use of ``Release`` and you as noted you don't need the call to ``GetResouce`` since the function gave it to you already. See [ComPtr](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/ComPtr) and [WICTextureLoader](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/WICTextureLoader)